# Bash script to test website status, then run command

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a very basic bash script, to run on a linux server. I am not sure why it's not working.

The intention is to test if a website returns a `200 OK` response. If it does, then exit. If it does not, then run a command.

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

if HEAD https://google.com | grep '200\ OK' | wc -l;  then
   echo "Site is up";
else
   sudo wo clean --all && sudo wo stack reload --all
fi
```

The issue is that if the site is up, it gives the expect output. Namely ...

```
1
Site is up
```

But if the site is down (say I replace `https://google.com` with `https://766google.com`, the output I get is:

```
0
Site is up
```

I've tried numerous variations, including put the `HEAD ...` command in `[ ]`.

For example, I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ HEAD https://google.com | grep '200\ OK' | wc -l ];  then
   echo "Site is up";
else
   sudo wo clean --all && sudo wo stack reload --all
fi
```

But then when the site is down, it runs the desired command, but gives an error ... I get this output:

```
./sitecheck.sh: line 3: [: missing `]'
wc: ]: No such file or directory
Cleaning NGINX FastCGI cache ... 
[THE OUTPUT OF COMMAND IT RUNS WHEN SITE IS DOWN]
```

Would someone please explain what is wrong with this script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of lines of output, you need to capture the pipeline's output with `$(...)`, and then use `((...))` to do an arithmetic comparison. One set of parentheses is output capturing; two sets is arithmetic.

```
if (($(HEAD https://google.com | grep '200 OK' | wc -l) > 0)); then
   echo "Site is up";
else
   sudo wo clean --all && sudo wo stack reload --all
fi
```

A simpler way to do this is to use `grep -q`. Instead of outputting matches, requiring you to parse `grep`'s output, `grep -q` directly returns a success or failure exit code indicating whether it found a match.

```
if HEAD https://google.com | grep -q '200 OK'; then
   echo "Site is up";
else
   sudo wo clean --all && sudo wo stack reload --all
fi
```

Comment: I literally realised this whilst you were likely typing your answer. That I was simply outputting a 0 or 1 as a count, not as a boolean (True/False).  Hence the issue. Thanks for sharing the correct way to go about it.

Comment: To simply exist the script for TRUE (instead of outputting "Site is up") am I correct in thinking I can simply use `exit 1` on that line?

Comment: Yep. `exit 1` if it's an error. `exit` or `exit 0` if it's success.